# Adjust limits of the two x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
Input <- ("Sp1  Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Sp5 Sp6
3   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   1   0")
comun <- read.table(textConnection(Input), header = TRUE)

library(vegan)
acumula <- specaccum(comun, method = "rarefaction")

plot_data <- data.frame("Sit" = c(0, acumula$sites),
                        "Ind" = c(0, acumula$individuals),
                        "Ric" = c(0, acumula$richness),
                        "lower" = c(0, acumula$richness - acumula$sd),
                        "upper" = c(0, acumula$richness + acumula$sd))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_data) +
        geom_line(aes(x = Sit, y = Ric),
                  color = "blue", lwd = 2) +
        geom_line(aes(x = Ind, y = Ric),
                  color = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2) +
        geom_ribbon(aes(x = Sit, y = Ric,
                        ymin = lower, ymax = upper), 
                    linetype = 2, alpha = 0.3, fill = "yellow") +
        geom_ribbon(aes(x = Ind, y = Ric,
                        ymin = lower, ymax = upper), 
                    linetype = 2, alpha = 0.3, fill = "yellow") +
        scale_x_continuous("Samples", 
                           sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., 
                                               name = "Individuals"), 
                           limits = c(0, 21)) +
        ylab("Accumulated Richness")
```

I would to set both x-axis limits to be coincident at the beginning and the end.

I would like the primary x-axis with limits 0 to 6 and the secondary x-axis 0 to 21. How can I perform it?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to change in the current plot ? Both the x-axis start at 0 and end at 20.

Comment: Yes, I would that x-axis to the blue line (below x-axis) has as limits c(0, 6) and the x-axis to the red line (above x-axis) has as limits c(0, 21). The values 6 and 21 represent the maximum values of each variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a secondary axis showing a different scale (or limits) you have to transform your data, e.g. you could do `scales::rescale(Sit, c(0, 21))` to rescale your `Sit` variable (to be plotted on the sec axis) to the range of your `Ind` variable (to be plotted on the primary x scale). In `sec_axis` you then have to apply the inverse transformation using e.g. `scales::rescale(., c(0, 6), c(0, 21))`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = scales::rescale(Sit, c(0, 21)), y = Ric),
    color = "blue", lwd = 2
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Ind, y = Ric),
    color = "red", lwd = 2, lty = 2
  ) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    x = scales::rescale(Sit, c(0, 21)), y = Ric,
    ymin = lower, ymax = upper
  ),
  linetype = 2, alpha = 0.3, fill = "yellow"
  ) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    x = Ind, y = Ric,
    ymin = lower, ymax = upper
  ),
  linetype = 2, alpha = 0.3, fill = "yellow"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous("Samples",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scales::rescale(., c(0, 6), c(0, 21)),
      name = "Individuals"
    )
  ) +
  ylab("Accumulated Richness")
```

[image]

Comment: Almost this. I wanna show these two lines in same graph, but these two lines has different scales for x-axis. The red line correspond to the Individuals x-axis. In final graph these lines will be exactly coincident just in their limits.
Like figure 3 in this site: [link](https://www.biosym.uzh.ch/modules/models/Biodiversity/MeasuresOfBioDiversity.html)
but just the rarefaction curves.

Comment: Hi @WilsonSouza. Unfortunately I'm afraid I can't help you on that as this is a matter of your data.